# Locust not startint without ctrl-c

Tags: locust

I have installed `locust==2.15.1` with pip.  Running on a windows environment.
When I execute `locust.exe` nothing happens until I press CTRL-C once then I get the following stacktrace and everything is running fine:

```
locust.exe

<CTRL-C>

Exception in thread loguru-writer-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venvs\myenv\lib\site-packages\loguru\_handler.py", line 270, in _queued_writer
    message = queue.get()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 366, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 221, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 310, in _recv_bytes
    waitres = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(
KeyboardInterrupt
[2023-05-31 13:52:25,102] computer/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network int
erfaces)
[2023-05-31 13:52:25,116] computer/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.15.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using loguru in your Locust file? Looks like it might be having an issue. Can you try a different locust file and see if it works?

Comment: @Solowalker great, this is it.  Without loguru it works.  If you convert your comment to an answer I can mark it as solution if you want ;)  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting looks like it's complaining about something having to do with the loguru package. Try running a different, simple locust file instead or at least remove loguru, if you're using it, and see what happens.